# Getting error when I'm trying to hash in SQL

Tags: sql, md5

I want to compare an string which is in clear text in the database with an string that is hashed with `MD5()`. I've tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT member_email, is_validated FROM members
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', 'member_email'), 2) = '".$_GET['vy']."'
AND is_validated = '0'
```

But I'm getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(32), HASHBYTES('MD5', 'member_email'), 2) = ''  AND is_valida' at line 2`. If I remove ' in `'member_email'` so it's `HASHBYTES('MD5', member_email)` I'll getting the same error message. What's wrong? Do I have to put the MD5 hash in the database to compare it with the same MD5 hash in `$_GET['vy']`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: isn't the lenght?  if you change (convert(255)(varchar,GETDATE(),102))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does MySQL have `HASHBYTES()`?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html

Have you tried:

```
SELECT member_email, is_validated FROM members
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), MD5(member_email), 2) = '".$_GET['vy']."'
AND is_validated = '0'
```

Comment: I noticed that `WHERE MD5(member_email) = '".$_GET['vy']."'` was more correct :) I did Googled for possible answers for my problem but I didn't find any solutions. Many thanks for the link and your answer!